# Is this a correct way to utilize classes and methods in JAVA?

Tags: java

I am currently learning JAVA. I barely have any coding experience. I wrote a program which asks a user for a sentence. It then swaps the words of the sentence (first with last, second with second to last, etc.). Program will then output the new sentence.

I know that this is not the most optimal way this task could be solved so please ignore that. 
My question is: **"Do I use classes and methods correctly? If not, how would I adjust them in this code? In particular, I feel my main method looks weird (the way parameters are added to the methods)."**

The code compiles and works as intended. My question is more in regards to style.

I add the code, in 2 classes

main class:

```
package com.test;

public class ND2_Task1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ND2_Task1_Core run = new ND2_Task1_Core();

        run.getInput(); // gets userSentence
        run.getWordCount(run.getUserSentence());
        run.checkValidity(run.getWordCount());
        run.toArray(run.getUserSentence()); // transforms String into an array
        run.reverseArray(run.getSeperatedSentence());
        run.showResult(run.getSeperatedSentence());

    }

}
```

2nd. class:

````
package com.test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ND2_Task1_Core {

    private static String userSentence;
    private static int wordCount;
    private static String[] seperatedSentence;
    private static String[] reversedSentence;

    public void getInput() {
        System.out.println(
                "Please enter a sentence.\nFirst word will be swapped with the last one.\nSecond word will be swapped with second to last\netc.");
        setUserSentence(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine());

    }

    public void getWordCount(String userSentence) {
        wordCount = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < userSentence.length(); i++) {
            if (userSentence.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                wordCount++;
            }
        }

    }

    public void checkValidity(int wordCount) {
        if (wordCount < 2) {
            System.out.println(
                    "You have entered an insufficient number of words. Enter at least 2 words for program to swap them");
            System.out.println("Exiting now");
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }

    public void toArray(String userSentence) {
        setSeperatedSentence(userSentence.split(" "));

    }

    public void reverseArray(String[] seperatedSentence) {
        reversedSentence = new String[seperatedSentence.length];

        reversedSentence = seperatedSentence;

        for (int i = 0; i < reversedSentence.length / 2; i++) {
            String temp = reversedSentence[i];
            reversedSentence[i] = reversedSentence[reversedSentence.length - i - 1];
            reversedSentence[reversedSentence.length - 1 - i] = temp;
        }

    }

    public void showResult(String[] reversedSentence) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(reversedSentence));

    }

    public String getUserSentence() {
        return userSentence;
    }

    public void setUserSentence(String userSentence) {
        ND2_Task1_Core.userSentence = userSentence;
    }

    public String[] getSeperatedSentence() {
        return seperatedSentence;
    }

    public void setSeperatedSentence(String[] seperatedSentence) {
        ND2_Task1_Core.seperatedSentence = seperatedSentence;
    }

    public int getWordCount() {
        return wordCount;
    }

    public void setWordCount(int wordCount) {
        ND2_Task1_Core.wordCount = wordCount;
    }

}
```
````

Comment: If you're just starting, then it doesn't matter too much.  Simple programs like this don't have an obvious "correct" way to write them.  They're mostly procedural anyway and don't really benefit from object oriented design.  When your assignments become more complex you'll see more opportunities to usefully use objects and breakdown code into structured design elements.  One criticism is that you've put all your code into a single object, which is normally a poor choice.  However the resulting object really isn't that complex, so it's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some suggestion for you.

## `ND2_Task1` class

Instead of adding comment near the methods calls, I suggest that you rename the method to a name that explains what it's doing and remove the comment. Also, most of the method that has parameters can be refactored to use the internal reference of the variable.

The best way to do this, is to think the `ND2_Task1_Core` class as a container that doesn’t expose the variables with getter or setters, but instead have methods to handle the data directly, so the `ND2_Task1` class can use them.

### `getInput` Method

I suggest that you rename this method to `askAndStoreUserSentenceInput` and remove the comment.

```java
public class ND2_Task1 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      //[...]
      ND2_Task1_Core run = new ND2_Task1_Core();
      run.askAndStoreUserSentenceInput();
      //[...]
   }
}
```

### `getWordCount` method

This method is more than a getter, since it updates the `wordCount`; the name can be confusing, I suggest `updateWordCount`.

```java
public class ND2_Task1 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      //[...]
      ND2_Task1_Core run = new ND2_Task1_Core();
      run.updateWordCount();
      //[...]
   }
}
```

### `checkValidity` method

Same for other methods, you can remove the parameter and uses the local variable.

```java
public class ND2_Task1 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      //[...]
      ND2_Task1_Core run = new ND2_Task1_Core();
      run.checkValidity();
      //[...]
   }
}

public class ND2_Task1_Core {
   //[...]
   public void checkValidity() {
      if (wordCount < 2) {
         System.out.println("You have entered an insufficient number of words. Enter at least 2 words for program to swap them");
         System.out.println("Exiting now");
         System.exit(0);
      }
   }
   //[...]
}
```

### `toArray` method

In my opinion, the name is confusing; since it does more than convert to an array (also set the result).

Personally, I suggest that you make a new method called `convertUserSentence` in the class `ND2_Task1_Core` that handle the logic.

**ND2_Task1**

```java
public class ND2_Task1 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      //[...]
      run.convertUserSentence();
      //[...]
   }
}
```

**ND2_Task1_Core**

```java
public class ND2_Task1_Core {
  //[...]
   public void convertUserSentence() {
      String userSentence = getUserSentence();
      setSeperatedSentence(userSentence.split(" "));
   }
   //[...]
}
```

### `reverseArray` method

You can remove the parameter and uses the local variable and rename the name to `reverseSentenceArray`.

**ND2_Task1**

```java
public class ND2_Task1 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      //[...]
      run.reverseSentenceArray();
      //[...]
   }
}
```

**ND2_Task1_Core**

```java
public class ND2_Task1_Core {
   //[...]
   public void reverseSentenceArray() {
      for (int i = 0; i < reversedSentence.length / 2; i++) {
         String temp = reversedSentence[i];
         reversedSentence[i] = reversedSentence[reversedSentence.length - i - 1];
         reversedSentence[reversedSentence.length - 1 - i] = temp;
      }
   }
   //[...]
}
```

### `showResult` method

**ND2_Task1**

```java
public class ND2_Task1 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      //[...]
      run.showResult();
      //[...]
   }
}
```

**ND2_Task1_Core**

```java
public class ND2_Task1_Core {
   //[...]
   public void showResult() {
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(reversedSentence));
   }
   //[...]
}
```

## `ND2_Task1_Core` class

1. The use of the `static` keyword on the variables is useless in this case, since you have only one instance of the class `ND2_Task1_Core`. The `static` is used to share the same value over all the instances of the same class.

```java
//[...]
private String userSentence;
private int wordCount;
private String[] seperatedSentence;
private String[] reversedSentence;
//[...]
```

2. Instead of creating a new instance of the `Scanner` each time you call the `getInput` method, I suggest that you store it in a variable.

```java
public class ND2_Task1_Core {
   private Scanner scanner;

   public ND2_Task1_Core() {
      scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   }

   public void getInput() {
      System.out.println("Please enter a sentence.\nFirst word will be swapped with the last one.\nSecond word will be swapped with second to last\netc.");
      setUserSentence(scanner.nextLine());
   }
}
```

## Refactored code

**ND2_Task1**

```java
public class ND2_Task1 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ND2_Task1_Core run = new ND2_Task1_Core();
      run.askAndStoreUserSentenceInput();
      run.updateWordCount();
      run.checkValidity();
      run.convertUserSentence();
      run.reverseSentenceArray();
      run.showResult();
   }
}
```

**ND2_Task1_Core**

```java
public class ND2_Task1_Core {
   private String userSentence;
   private int wordCount;
   private String[] seperatedSentence;
   private String[] reversedSentence;
   private Scanner scanner;

   public ND2_Task1_Core() {
      scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   }

   public void askAndStoreUserSentenceInput() {
      System.out.println("Please enter a sentence.\nFirst word will be swapped with the last one.\nSecond word will be swapped with second to last\netc.");
      setUserSentence(scanner.nextLine());
   }

   public void updateWordCount() {
      wordCount = 1;
      for (int i = 0; i < userSentence.length(); i++) {
         if (userSentence.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            wordCount++;
         }
      }
   }

   public void checkValidity() {
      if (wordCount < 2) {
         System.out.println("You have entered an insufficient number of words. Enter at least 2 words for program to swap them");
         System.out.println("Exiting now");
         System.exit(0);
      }
   }

   public void reverseSentenceArray() {
      for (int i = 0; i < reversedSentence.length / 2; i++) {
         String temp = reversedSentence[i];
         reversedSentence[i] = reversedSentence[reversedSentence.length - i - 1];
         reversedSentence[reversedSentence.length - 1 - i] = temp;
      }
   }

   public void showResult() {
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(reversedSentence));
   }

   public String getUserSentence() {
      return userSentence;
   }

   public void setUserSentence(String userSentence) {
      this.userSentence = userSentence;
   }

   public String[] getSeperatedSentence() {
      return seperatedSentence;
   }

   public void setSeperatedSentence(String[] seperatedSentence) {
      this.seperatedSentence = seperatedSentence;
   }

   public int getWordCount() {
      return wordCount;
   }

   public void setWordCount(int wordCount) {
      this.wordCount = wordCount;
   }

   public void convertUserSentence() {
      String userSentence = getUserSentence();
      setSeperatedSentence(userSentence.split(" "));
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for and it will help me improve my understanding of how coding works a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be under the impression that efficient code and good design are two separate things.  A good design will help you write efficient code.

In this particular case, you need to learn about separation of concern.  Specifically what is the user concerned about and what should be handled by the class?

The user basically just wants the words in the supplied string swapped.  Everything else should be handled inside the class.

In the class itself, you don't really need all those properties and helper methods.  The main purpose of the code can easily be summed in one function.  I would suggest a utility class(`StringUtils`?) with a public static function to swap the words and return a string.

The solution could look like this:

Main.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sentence;
    System.out.println(
        "Please enter a sentence.\nFirst word will be swapped with the last one.\nSecond word will be swapped with second to last\netc.");
    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
      sentence = sc.nextLine(); 
    }   
    String swapped = StringUtils.swapWords(sentence);
    System.out.println(swapped);
  }
}
```

StringUtils.java

```
public class StringUtils {

  public static String swapWords(String input) {
    String[] usersWords = input.split(" ");
    if(usersWords.length < 2){
      inputError();
    }
    String[] words = new String[usersWords.length];
    int mid = (words.length / 2) + 1;
    for (int front = 0, back = words.length - 1; front < mid; ++front, --back) {
      words[front] = usersWords[back];
      words[back] = usersWords[front];
    }
    return String.join(" ", words);
  }

  private static void inputError(){
            System.out.println(
                    "You have entered an insufficient number of words. Enter at least 2 words for program to swap them");
            System.out.println("Exiting now");
            System.exit(0);   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm agree with all considerations expressed by @tinstaafl in his [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/236531/203649), so I'm adding just two thoughts.

First point: I noticed that you used the `Arrays` class in your code so if you want to reverse the String `words` array without any loop but just using the standard library you can do in one line with the help of `Collections` class like below:

```
Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(words));
```

The cost is the creation of one `List` object , but it is a concise solution.

Second point : you called your classes `ND2_Task1` and `ND2_Task1_Core` ; following the [java code conventions for class names](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html):

> Class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of
>   each internal word capitalized.

So you could rename them `Nd2Task1` and `Nd2Task1Core`.